# Parsing RTF with pyparsing

Tags: rtf, pyparsing

I'm trying to implement simple general RTF parser with pyparsing. But now I'm stuck at strange error:

```
    #Code:
    control_codes = Word('\\;*' + alphanums)
    start = Word('{')
    end = Word('}') | (Word(';') + Word('}'))
    header = OneOrMore(control_codes | Word(alphanums))

    document = Forward()
    document <<= (
        start +
        header +
        (document + end) | end
    )
    print document.parseString('{\\*\\falt Times New Roman}')

    #Error
    pyparsing.ParseException: Expected W:(}) (at char 25), (line:1, col:26)
```

Char 25 is '}', it's the latest character in string.
This is simplest example, more complicated examples that I tried to use, were cut some part of input string.

Answer (score 1):

You actually have a number of errors in this snippet, and you might want to revisit some of the pyparsing docs to make sure you have the basics down.

`Word(stringOfChars)` will match a group of characters that all exist in the given `stringOfChars`.  `Word(alphanums)` will match "ABC","slkjfljlsdflsdjf", "2330098324", "392084lsfd0238" and so on. So `Word("{")` will match not only "{", but also "{{" and "{{{{{{{{" - in several of these places where you are defining punctuation marks, I think you more likely mean to use `Literal`, not `Word`. `Literal` will match only the exact string used in its constructor, with no implicit repetition.

`Word(string1, string2)` will match a group of characters that start with one of the characters in `string1`, followed immediately by zero or more characters in `string2`. In your definition of `controlCodes`, I think you want to only accept a leading '\' character, followed by 1 or more `alphanums`, '*', or ';'. This would be more correctly written as `Word('\\', alphanums+'*'+';')`

Since you parsing RTF which frequently includes '\' characters, you will make progress faster if you use Python raw string literals, which will let you enter strings containing backslashes without having to double them up. Compare

```
print document.parseString('{\\*\\falt Times New Roman}')
```

and

```
print document.parseString(r'{\*\falt Times New Roman}')
```

The only catch is that you still have to double up a backslash if it is the last (or only) character in the string.

The problem you are getting is that your definition of `header` consumes too much of the input.  Try adding these lines after defining `header`:

```
header.setName("header")
header.setDebug()
```

This will print out diagnostic messages every time `header` is reached in the parser, and show if the parse succeeded or failed. If the parse succeeded, it will also show what was matched.  Here is what you get from parsing your example text:

```
Match header at loc 1(1,2)
Matched header -> ['\\', '*', '\\falt', 'Times', 'New', 'Roman']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rtf.py", line 26, in <module>
    print document.parseString(r'{\*\falt Times New Roman}')
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1041, in parseString
    raise exc
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "}" (at char 1), (line:1, col:2)
```

I don't think you expected `header` to go all the way to read "Times New Roman".

If you have not taken to time to rough out a BNF for your parser, I strongly encourage you to do so. Once you have this written down, try to follow the BNF through your test string - be as literal as you can, make NO assumptions about where `OneOrMore` expressions should stop because "it's obvious". Pyparsing doesn't do any lookahead that you don't tell it to do.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I've solved the issue in this topic. pyparsing is greate library as I see.